# Angular Universal SSR + JSDOM + Webpack : Can't resolve 'canvas'

Tags: webpack, canvas, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, jsdom

I am trying to use jsdom to create window and document objects for my SSR Angular project. However, I am experiencing this error. I am using the window to attempt to initialize the jQuery library (to list all its method).

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'canvas' in '/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom'
```

**Exactly like on this issue** https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3042

I tried a proposed solution which is preventing Webpack to bundle canvas with jsdom.

with

```
plugins: [
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
        resourceRegExp: /canvas/,
        contextRegExp: /jsdom$/,
      }),
    ],
```

This gives me the following error

```
Compiled successfully.
/server/main.js:168664
const AsyncIteratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf( /*#__PURE__*/_wrapAsyncGenerator(function* () {})).prototype);
                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
```

which seems to have been fixed already according to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21735 but not in the initial code according to
https://github.com/MattiasBuelens/web-streams-polyfill/blob/master/src/target/es2018/stub/async-iterator-prototype.ts

I tried also to **install canvas**, but it's a node module it does not get along with Webpack. It leads to another error

```
./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

So tried to **install node-loader** as this issue recommend https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1314

with

```
module.exports = (config, context) => {
  return merge(config, {
    target: 'node',
    node: {
      __dirname: false,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.node$/,
          loader: 'node-loader',
        },
      ],
    },
  });
};
```

and also tried **without node-loader** with

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (config, context) => {
  return merge(config, {
    target: 'node', // Important (1)
    externals: {
      canvas: 'commonjs canvas', // Important (2)
    },
  });
};
```

Which states

```
(1) indicates the bundle needs to be made to run with Node.js. (2) indicates that canvas shouldn't be bundled, and instead be loaded with a normal require("canvas") statement.
```

but the problem remains the same. No change in both.

```
const AsyncIteratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf( /*#__PURE__*/_wrapAsyncGenerator(function* () {})).prototype);
                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

**My question is, how can I load a window object from JSDOM in a 'dummy' Angular SSR backend with this below code in server.ts**

```
import { DOMWindow, JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const window: DOMWindow = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html>', { url: 'http://localhost' }).window;
```

**Thanks** for any clue on how to solve this and for reading.

Comment: I made a reproducible repository of the issue

https://github.com/gRoussac/angular-universal-jsdom

Comment: I am having the same problem, do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the `canvas` package from webpack  using `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`

You need to add this to `extra-webpack-config.ts`:

```
config.externals.push({ canvas: {} })
```

Alternatively you can add the node module loader to webpack if you really need canvas in the SSR-site.

Make sure that `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` is used for the SSR in `angular.json`.

```
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.ts"
            },
```